# What does "MOVOU" mean in golang assembly

Tags: assembly, go, x86

When I was reading some Golang's asm codes, I found `MOVOU`. And I can't get anything about this instruction by searching on Google.

For example: [src/runtime/asm_amd64.s#L933](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s#L933)

```
MOVOU   -16(AX), X1
```

Comment: Well, +1 -- it doesn't seem to be mentioned in x64 instruction sets, so it is kind of unusual to find it in working code. A comment in one of these sources remarks "MOVOU seems always faster than REP STOSL." but that's about it.

Comment: Related: [Add MOVDQA and MOVDQU instructions](https://codereview.appspot.com/133740043/)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary thank you. That's what I need. The O stands for octo-word. How did you find that? I have tried many ways but nothing found

Comment: @templexxx Glad that helped. My query was **"movou" in golang**, it lead me to: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/aPjvemV4F0U/lPv5rJeOhfMJ

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I never tried  "" & in. That's funny. I think I need to spend more time on how to search on Google. Thank you

Comment: From that page: ".. SSE registers are X0...X15. MOVDQA is called MOVO (or MOVOA) and MOVDQU is called MOVOU." But why isn't it in x86 opcode listings? Even an explicit search for `sse movou` yields mainly those same Go-Lang sources!

Comment: Because Golang has invented their own assembly language, @rad. MOVO and MOVOU are *not* Intel-defined opcodes.

Comment: @RadLexus For example: Golang has no SUB but SUBQ

Comment: @CodyGray Correction: Go took the Plan 9 assembly language and extended it to support SSE and AVX.  The Plan 9 assembler was primarily designed to have identical syntax and opcodes on all platforms, which is why its mnemonics are different from Intel's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are lots of weird names, inconsistencies and issues in Go x86 syntax.

As already pointed in comments, the MOVOU is MOVDQU.

I try to maintain [Go assembly complementary reference](https://quasilyte.github.io/blog/post/go-asm-complementary-reference/), which fills some documentation gaps of official documentation, but currently it's pretty out-of-date and requires some cleanup.
Planning to write AVX512 details there, when [implementation details](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/22779) are stabilized. 
I hope it is useful for quick `ctrl+F` search for some Go asm questions.

For your particular question, it's definitely useful:

[image]

You may find [x86.v0.2.csv](https://github.com/golang/arch/blob/master/x86/x86.v0.2.csv) useful, as it gives you Intel, GNU and Go syntax for each listed instruction.
As `v0.2` in name suggests, there will be updates and fixes in future.

To make things worse, there are [aliases](https://quasilyte.github.io/blog/files/go_x86_aliases.txt) that allow you to write, for example, `PADDD` instead of `PADDL`.
This is unlikely to ever change due to backwards-compatibility.

To avoid completely negative impression, there are some stuff that Go asm "does well". For example, it checks immediate operands widths for instructions that expect only lower N bits to be set. 
It also does not permit negative constants for "unsigned" immediate operands.
(as a bonus, here is an issue that contains some Russ Cox thoughts on this topic: [issue21528](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21528).)

Comment: So Go uses O (as in Oct-word) everywhere instead of DQ (double-quad)?  Intel hasn't been consistent either (`cqo` mnemonic vs. SSE2 and other SIMD instructions), although maybe that's AMD's fault.  I guess AMD64 introduced the `cqo` mnemonic.  Heh, we could have had `cqdq` to go with `punpcklqdq` if Intel had been naming things.

Comment: @PeterCordes, starting from AVX, it's Intel instruction names. If any of them mismatch -- it's a bug. Prior to that, I don't think stuff like "everywhere" applies, because there are lot's of inconsistencies here and there.

Comment: So Go uses `vmovdqa (AX), x1` for an AVX-128 load, but `movo (AX), x1` for the non-VEX legacy SSE encoding (which leaves the upper part of ymm1 / zmm1 unmodified)?  That's interesting...  But yes, probably good to stop making up their own names; it could get really confusing really quickly once you start to get Intel instruction mnemonics that include numbers, too, like AVX512BW `vmovdqu8` (which masks with 8-bit granularity) or [`VSHUFF32x4`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/VSHUFF32x4_VSHUFF64x2_VSHUFI32x4_VSHUFI64x2) (different granularity masking for 128b lane shuffles)

Comment: @PeterCordes, yes, that is correct, `VMOVDQA` for AVX1 instruction.